# Spark Thrift Server and ODBC

Tags: apache-spark, spark-thriftserver

I have Spark 2.2 installed but not Hive and I would like to expose Spark tables through ODBC. I am able to start thrift server , with apparently no errors and my ODBC driver application is able to connect to thrift sever, but can’t see any Spark tables. Do I need to have Hive installed up and running in order to my ODBC applications access the Spark tables that I create?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spark uses Hive metastore.
You need to setup hiveserver as well to get access to hive tables.